# How do I use numba for the following code?

Tags: python, performance, numba

I am trying to use Numba for the first time in colab and I think I have successfully installed Numba since the @jit is not undefined now but I am getting errors in my code. The following is my attempt:

```
!apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
!pip3 install numba
import os
dev_lib_path = !find / -iname 'libdevice'
nvvm_lib_path = !find / -iname 'libnvvm.so'
assert len(dev_lib_path)>0, "Device Lib Missing"
assert len(nvvm_lib_path)>0, "NVVM Missing"
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = dev_lib_path[0]
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = nvvm_lib_path[0]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from math import *
from random import *
from numba import jit
n=1000
mu=np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
r=[sqrt(-2*log(1-i)) for i in mu]
eta=np.random.uniform(0,1,n)
theta=2*pi*eta;
cuz=[cos(i) for i in theta]
suz=[sin(i) for i in theta]
Zinitial=[a*b for a,b in zip(r,cuz)];
Pinitial=[a*b for a,b in zip(r,suz)];

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, pos, mom, spin):
        self.pos = pos
        self.mom = mom
        self.spin = spin
   
SP = sorted(np.array([Particle(pos = i, mom = j, spin = choice([1, 0])) for i,j in zip(Zinitial,Pinitial)]),key=lambda x:x.pos)
Upi=[];
Downi=[];
count_plot=[];
for j in range(len(SP)):
    if SP[j].spin == 1:
        Upi.append(SP[j].pos)
    else:
        Downi.append(SP[j].pos)
Zavgi=sum(Zinitial)/len(Zinitial)
Zreli=sum(Upi)/len(Upi)-sum(Downi)/len(Downi)
"Observables"


"Time"

iter=10**(5);
dt=1/(2*n);
alf=sqrt(n);

"Dynamics"




@jit(nopython=True)
def f(): 
  counter=0;
  sum1,sum2=0,0;
  Zavg=[Zavgi];
  Zrelm=[Zreli];
  T_plot=[0];
  for i in range(1,iter+1):
        
        t=i*dt;
        T_plot.append(t) 
        Z=[];
        Up=[];
        Down=[];
        c,s=cos(t),sin(t);
        c1,s1=cos(t-dt),sin(t-dt);
        for j in range(n-1):
            collchk=((c*(SP[j].pos)+s*(SP[j].mom))-(c*(SP[j+1].pos)+s*(SP[j+1].mom)))*(c1*(SP[j].pos)+s1*(SP[j].mom)-(c1*(SP[j+1].pos)+s1*(SP[j+1].mom)));

            prel=((c*(SP[j].mom)-s*(SP[j].pos))-(c*(SP[j+1].mom)-s*(SP[j+1].pos)))/2;
               
            rcoeff=1/(1+(prel*alf)**2);
            rand_value=random();
            
            
            if collchk<0:
               
              
               SP[j], SP[j+1]=SP[j+1],SP[j];
               
              
               if rcoeff>rand_value:
                   counter=counter+1
                   SP[j].spin,SP[j+1].spin=SP[j+1].spin,SP[j].spin;
            if SP[j].spin == 1:
                Up.append(c*(SP[j].pos)+s*(SP[j].mom))
            else:
                Down.append(c*(SP[j].pos)+s*(SP[j].mom))
            Z.append(c*(SP[j].pos)+s*(SP[j].mom))

        
        
        Zrel=sum(Up[0:])/len(Up) - sum(Down[0:])/len(Down);
        Zrelm.append(Zrel)
                        
        Zm=sum(Z)/len(Z)
        Zavg.append(Zm)
  return [Zavg, Zrelm, counter]
```

Th error that I get with Vandan's code given below:

```
     Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'sum': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

File "<ipython-input-1-cddc88c01635>", line 52:
def f(SP, Zavgi, Zreli, alf, dt, n):
    <source elided>

        Zrel = sum(Up[0:]) / len(Up) - sum(Down[0:]) / len(Down);
        ^
```

In the end I want to plot the lists that I have returned.
Any help would be appreciated and if there is a way to use Numba even for the class definiton that would be great.

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from math import *
from random import *
from numba import jit




"Dynamics"

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(SP, Zavgi, Zreli, alf, dt, n):
    "Time"
    counter = 0;
    sum1, sum2 = 0, 0;
    Zavg = np.array([Zavgi]);
    Zrelm = np.array([Zreli]);
    T_plot = [0];
    for i in range(1, iter + 1):

        t = i * dt;
        T_plot.append(t)
        Z = [];
        Up = [];
        Down = [];
        c, s = cos(t), sin(t);
        c1, s1 = cos(t - dt), sin(t - dt);
        for j in range(n - 1):
            collchk = ((c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1])) - (c * (SP[j + 1][0]) + s * (SP[j + 1][1]))) * (
                    c1 * (SP[j][0]) + s1 * (SP[j][1]) - (c1 * (SP[j + 1][0]) + s1 * (SP[j + 1][1])));

            prel = ((c * (SP[j][1]) - s * (SP[j][0])) - (c * (SP[j + 1][1]) - s * (SP[j + 1][0]))) / 2;

            rcoeff = 1 / (1 + (prel * alf) ** 2);
            rand_value = random();

            if collchk < 0:

                SP[j], SP[j + 1] = SP[j + 1], SP[j];

                if rcoeff > rand_value:
                    counter = counter + 1
                    SP[j][2], SP[j + 1][2] = SP[j + 1][2], SP[j][2];
            if SP[j][2] == 1:
                Up.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))
            else:
                Down.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))
            Z.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))

        Zrel = sum(Up[0:]) / len(Up) - sum(Down[0:]) / len(Down);
        Zrelm = np.append(Zrelm, Zrel)

        Zm = sum(Z) / len(Z)
        Zavg = np.append(Zavg, Zm)
        
        
    return Zavg, Zrelm, counter,T_plot



if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 1000
    mu = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    r = [sqrt(-2 * log(1 - i)) for i in mu]
    eta = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    theta = 2 * pi * eta;
    cuz = [cos(i) for i in theta]
    suz = [sin(i) for i in theta]
    Zinitial = [a * b for a, b in zip(r, cuz)];
    Pinitial = [a * b for a, b in zip(r, suz)];

    iter = 10 ** (6);
    dt = 1 / (100 * n);
    alf = sqrt(n);


    SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([  np.array([i,j,choice([0,1])]) for i, j in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial)]),
                key=lambda x: x[0]))
    Upi = [];
    Downi = [];
    count_plot = [];
    for j in range(len(SP)):
        if SP[j][2] == 1:
            Upi.append(SP[j][0])
        else:
            Downi.append(SP[j][0])
    Zavgi = sum(Zinitial) / len(Zinitial)
    Zreli = sum(Upi) / len(Upi) - sum(Downi) / len(Downi)


    Zavg, Zrelm, counter,T_plot = f(SP, Zavgi, Zreli, alf, dt, n)

    plt.plot(T_plot, Zrelm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a bit and was able to get the function to run. I removed the Particle class and changed all the list instances to numpy arrays.

This is the output for the Zavg, Zrelm and counter:

```
Zavg: [0.07047501 0.06735052 0.06728123 ... 0.39516435 0.3947497  0.39433495] 
Zrelm: [-0.04179043 -0.04461464 -0.0394889  ... -0.11080628 -0.11087257
     -0.11093883] 
Counter: 538
```

---

Here is the modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from math import *
from random import *
from numba import jit


"Dynamics"

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(SP, Zavgi, Zreli, alf, dt, n):
    "Time"
    counter = 0;
    sum1, sum2 = 0, 0;
    Zavg = np.array([Zavgi]);
    Zrelm = np.array([Zreli]);
    T_plot = [0];
    for i in range(1, iter + 1):

        t = i * dt;
        T_plot.append(t)
        Z = [];
        Up = [];
        Down = [];
        c, s = cos(t), sin(t);
        c1, s1 = cos(t - dt), sin(t - dt);
        for j in range(n - 1):
            collchk = ((c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1])) - (c * (SP[j + 1][0]) + s * (SP[j + 1][1]))) * (
                    c1 * (SP[j][0]) + s1 * (SP[j][1]) - (c1 * (SP[j + 1][0]) + s1 * (SP[j + 1][1])));

            prel = ((c * (SP[j][1]) - s * (SP[j][0])) - (c * (SP[j + 1][1]) - s * (SP[j + 1][0]))) / 2;

            rcoeff = 1 / (1 + (prel * alf) ** 2);
            rand_value = random();

            if collchk < 0:

                SP[j], SP[j + 1] = SP[j + 1], SP[j];

                if rcoeff > rand_value:
                    counter = counter + 1
                    SP[j][2], SP[j + 1][2] = SP[j + 1][2], SP[j][2];
            if SP[j][2] == 1:
                Up.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))
            else:
                Down.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))
            Z.append(c * (SP[j][0]) + s * (SP[j][1]))

        Zrel = np.sum(np.array(Up)) / len(Up) - np.sum(np.array(Down)) / len(Down);
        Zrelm = np.append(Zrelm, Zrel)

        Zm = np.sum(np.array(Z)) / len(Z)
        Zavg = np.append(Zavg, Zm)


    return Zavg, Zrelm, counter, T_plot



if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 1000
    mu = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    r = [sqrt(-2 * log(1 - i)) for i in mu]
    eta = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    theta = 2 * pi * eta;
    cuz = [cos(i) for i in theta]
    suz = [sin(i) for i in theta]
    Zinitial = [a * b for a, b in zip(r, cuz)];
    Pinitial = [a * b for a, b in zip(r, suz)];

    iter = 10 ** (5);
    dt = 1 / (2 * n);
    alf = sqrt(n);


    SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([  np.array([i,j,choice([0,1])]) for i, j in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial)]),
                key=lambda x: x[0]))
    Upi = [];
    Downi = [];
    count_plot = [];
    for j in range(len(SP)):
        if SP[j][2] == 1:
            Upi.append(SP[j][0])
        else:
            Downi.append(SP[j][0])
    Zavgi = sum(Zinitial) / len(Zinitial)
    Zreli = sum(Upi) / len(Upi) - sum(Downi) / len(Downi)


    Zavg, Zrelm, counter, T_plot = f(SP, Zavgi, Zreli, alf, dt, n)

    print(Zavg, Zrelm, counter)
    plt.plot(T_plot, Zrelm)
    plt.show()
```

This is how the plot looks like:
[image: wave]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but it doesn't run for me.  I have edited my question to include the error that occurs.

Comment: You can not possibly get a global name error with my code since we are passing SP as a parameter to the function. Could you properly edit your question with correct error? @Lost

Comment: You are correct. That was the error I was getting with my code. With yours, I am getting something regarding sum. I have edited the error and also the last part of the code to include how I am trying to plot the arrays with time.

Comment: I have replaced sum with np.sum. It now gives you the plot like how you intend it to. Try it out. If it solves your question, please select my answer as the selected answer by pressing the tick icon next to the answer. @Lost

Comment: I tried to run my code smaller times without Numba once with the class method and once with the array method. It turns out that with the array method I get a lot of fizziness in the graphs. Is it possible to run the Numba without converting SP to an array while keeping it a class?

Comment: Numba only supports Numpy built-in types by default. And as @Jerome said in his answer, Numba has no idea what your Particle class means. Maybe you could try the experimental support for jitted classes. Check this page: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245150/discussion-between-vandan-revanur-and-lost).

Comment: It turns out that there was a sneaky bug in the implementation in the end. See [Why deploying Numba and using arrays instead of class gives different results for the same parameters in my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425334).

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because Numba try to access to global variable which the type is not known at compile time. Indeed, `SP` is a pure-Python list called **reflected list** which can contain items of different types. Numba does not support such kind of list anymore. Instead, Numba supports **typed lists** which are compatible with reflected lists. This means you need to build a new typed list (with a well-defined type) and copy the reflected list items to the typed list. This process can be quite expensive compared to the overall computation. Thus, this is often better not to use lists when arrays can be used instead (typically when you cannot know the size of the final list): Numpy array are significantly faster, more compact and functions using them can be compiled faster.

Additionally, Numba has no idea of was is the type `Particle`. Numba only supports Numpy built-in types by default. There is an *experimental* support for *jitted classes* but I advise you to work with basic array since it is generally faster and also more flexible as you can use Numpy vectorized functions on the target arrays as opposed to an object-based array (which are AFAIK inefficiently stored in Numpy arrays and slow).

Moreover, you should really avoid using global variables, especially the ones that are mutated. Global variables are slower to access in CPython and are generally seen as a bad software engineering practice. For Numba, they are considered as compile time constant so it can cause some surprising results if the variables are mutated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am not sure how to convert my class with three instances to an array I am trying to study Vandan's code which also shows errors. "Moreover, you should really avoid using global variables, especially the ones that are mutated. Global variables are slower to access in CPython and are generally seen as a bad software engineering practice" Are "sum" and "len" also considered as global variables in python?

Comment: The idea is to transform the list of particle object to multiple arrays of native types. Typically one for the position, another for the moment and another for the spin. This is how people using Numpy usually implement that. Alternatively, you can use a unique array of a [composite type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) however this is often less flexible and less efficient (since Numpy cannot use SIMD instructions -- in fact, the same issue applies for basic POO codes).

Comment: `sum` and `len` are built-in function so it is not a problem (though it is not a good idea the mutate them still). More generally, having global function is fine. Global constants are relatively fine too (eg. integer or floats), especially with simple types. Mutated global are not (except in very very few specific cases). The main problem with global is they spooky action at distance that often cause weird behaviours, make optimizations much harder (especially parallelization of codes).

Comment: For example if you do `sum = len` then some modules will simply crash with weird errors. As for basic variables, you can end up with side effects (data corruption) in functions that are supposed to read/get some results due to an indirect modifications of globals. This makes the debugging much harder.